# ''Expected ';' after top level declarator“ and ”Unknown type name 'namespace'

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm using react-native-pusher-push-notifications to get notifications in my app  when trying to compile my app ,I got this error:

Unknown type name 'namespace'

```
namespace std{ //Expected ';' after top level declarator      
using :: va_list;   
}
```

I tried to fix my code in this way but got the same error :

```
#ifndef __CSTDARG_HEADER   #define __CSTDARG_HEADER    
#include <stdarg.h>      
namespace std{        
using :: va_list;   
}    
#else    
typedef struct std std; // Sets up incomplete type for C code    
#endif
```

Comment: Have you solved it, I am getting same error.